# Getting cannot POST / error in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, kue

I have a RESTful API that I am using postman to make a call to my route /websites. Whenever I make the call, postman says "Cannot POST /websites". I am trying to implement a job queue and I'm using Express, Kue(Redis) and MongoDB.

Here is my routes file:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(app) {
// Create a new website
const websites = require('./controllers/website.controller.js');
app.post('/websites', function(req, res) {
  const content = req.body;
  websites.create(content, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.json({
        error: err,
        success: false,
        message: 'Could not create content',
      });
    } else {
      return res.json({
        error: null,
        success: true,
        message: 'Created a website!', content
      });
    }
  })
});
}
```

Here is the server file:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const kue = require('kue');
const websites = require('./app/routes/website.routes.js')
kue.app.listen(3000);

var app = express();

const redis = require('redis');
const client = redis.createClient();
client.on('connect', () =>{
  console.log('Redis connection established');
})

app.use('/websites', websites);
```

I've never used Express and I have no idea what is going on here. Any amount of help would be great!!
Thank you!

Comment: Can you post here the complete error message from Postman? Thanks

Comment: Sure! It's just "Cannot POST /websites"

Comment: This means that `app.post('/websites')` api handler was not registered and express can't find it. Can you also post your code for the app.js file?

Comment: I added it to the question! I didn't use app.js so there is nothing in it but I think you're looking for this file!

Comment: It should be `app.listen(3000);` to run the server on a specific port in express. Then on your routes it should be `app.post('/api');` so that you may call it like `http://<YOUR_HOST>:3000/websites/api`

Comment: You are doing so many things wrong here!

Comment: Thanks @CodeLover!! And like what @robert-moskal? Like I said, I am unfamiliar with node in general and I'm trying to learn.

Comment: Did it work now @ShannonNolan?

Comment: as per your routes creation your /websites api end point will work at (http://<YOUR_HOST>:3000/websites/websites)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is how you are using the app.use and the app.post. You have.

```
app.use('/websites', websites);
```

And inside websites you have:

```
app.post('/websites', function....
```

So to reach that code you need to make a post to `localhost:3000/websites/websites`. What you need to do is simply remove the `/websites` from your routes.

```
//to reach here post to localhost:3000/websites
app.post('/' , function(req, res) {

});
```